# Creating a double delegate with TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

This is my situation: I've got a viewController which contains a tableViewController embedded in a container view. Then, I have three classes: TableViewCell, TableViewController and the ViewController. In the prototype cell there's a button that's connected to the TableViewCell class. When someone presses the button in that cell, I want a method in my ViewController to be run. To do so, I created some protocols and delegates, directing the button-press to the ViewController.

Let me show you my code:

This is my TableViewCell file:

```
protocol TVCDelegate {
func cellClicked()
}

Class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  var delegate: OtherVCDelegate?

  @IBAction func buyUpgrade(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.cellClicked()
  }

}
```

This is my TableViewController file:

```
protocol TVCToVCDelegate {
func sendThrough()
}

Class TableViewController: UITableViewController, TVCDelegate {

func cellClicked() {
    self.delegate?.sendThrough()
}

open var delegate: UTVToVCDelegate?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
        }

        // Configure the cell...            
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
}
```

Then, my ViewController file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UTVToVCDelegate {

  //MARK: Delegate Methods
  func sendThrough() {
      print("The delegate was completed succesfully")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      UpgradesTableViewController.delegate = self
  //ERROR: Instance member delegate can not be used on type 'TableViewController'
  }
}
```

However, there's an error message that the instance member delegate can not be used on type 'TableViewController'.

I do not know how to resolve the issue, maybe someone could help, please?
Thanks

Comment: How is the instance of the `TableViewController` created and added as a child of `ViewController`? Is it done through code (show that code) or through a storyboard?

Comment: It’s added through a storyboard.

Comment: In the storyboard I placed a container view in the VC then control-dragged from the container to the tableVC to select 'embed in'.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like your problem is, your UIViewController does not know about any Instance of your TableViewController Class. You need to instantiate the TableViewController in your UIViewController, so you can assign the delegate to it.

edit: In your case, you need to drag the outlet from your storyboard to the UIViewController and set the delegate.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: See the response from rmaddy

Comment: See what I wrote to rmaddy :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't use the `delegate` property on the `UpgradesTableViewController` class itself. You need to set the `delegate` property on an instance of `UpgradesTableViewController`.

Add an outlet to your `ViewController` as follows:

```
@IBOutlet var tableViewController: UpgradesTableViewController!
```

Then connect the table view controller in the storyboard to this outlet in your `ViewController`.

Finally, change the line:

```
UpgradesTableViewController.delegate = self
```

to:

```
tableViewController.delegate = self
```

Comment: I can't connect the Table View Controller as an outlet to the ViewController... This is what I've got in my Storyboard: ViewController. Container view in that ViewController. A separate Table View Controller with an 'embed' link to the container.